# Why does external dependencies added in Project Structure doesn't appear in compile time (Intellij)?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, dependencies, external

So I've created a library which is not released as not tested, so I'm importing it manually using the Project structure to test it out, just like [explained in here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html).

Here's a snapshot as well:

[image]

And it even seems that it is imported in the intellij as it is shown in the editor, as well as I can navigate to its definition.

But unfortunately the build fails see this:

[image]

**And i tried changing the scoped of the dependency, but nothing worked.**

How could I solve this, any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it working by removing external dependencies I had added manually from Intellij IDEA's Project structure.

And add the external dependencies by using the gradle:

```kotlin
compile files('path/to/the/jar/my-plugin.main.jar')
```

This `file()` uses project's folder as root, then we can navigate through that.

Issue may have been occured because of using both gradle and intellij project management at the same time.

Hopefully if somebody having same issue, he/she may fix it using gradle.